# "Dynamic" parts in URL

Tags: c#, url-rewriting

The application i'm making starts Internet Explorer with a specific URL.
for instance, this fake url:

```
&aqi=g10&aql="3"&oq="3"
```

how can i change that url into this one:

```
&aqi=g10&aql="2"&oq="2"
```

by using an item from a combobox?

What i'm trying to do is changing a part of the URL with selecting an item in a combobox and then executing the URL in IE.

anyone ideas?

(not sure if the title is right)

thanks in advance

Comment: Now that I've re-read your question - is this a Winforms application? If so, please tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to do, you can get the query string parameters with `Request.QueryString`, do the manipulations as per the selections in the combobox, then build the new URL and redirect to it with `Response.Redirect`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4.aspx

Something like:

```
// get the URL from the Request and remove the query string part
string newUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace(Request.Url.Query, "");

newUrl += string.Format("?aqi={0}&aql={1}&oq={2}",
    Request.QueryString["aqi"], ddlAql.SelectedValue, ddlOq.SelectedValue);

Response.Redirect(newUrl);
```

Comment: Can you give me an example with the url I supplied?

Comment: @Erik - I added a rough example.

Comment: You should check that newUrl != original URL or you will be in an endless redirect.

Comment: @jamietre: The only thing that would cause an endless redirect is if the redirect is executed as part of the page load.

Answer (score 0):

Build the url in code:

```
string url = "&aqi=g10&aql=\"" + comboBox1.Text + "\"&oq=\"" + comboBox2.Text + \"";
```

Comment: what if I want to use a string instead of Combobox*.Text?